# Add LIMIT query in php

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add LIMIT query in it? I have adding it in

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM eins_policy LIMIT 500 ";
```

but it did not display the list.

[image]

For example:

- If I choose 500 records per page;
- Total records is 3560 records;
- If now I on page 1, meaning (Page number – 1) * 500 = 0, and my  Offset is 0;
- If now I on page 2, meaning (Page number – 1) * 500 = (2 – 1) * 500 = 500, and Offset is 500, meaning 501 to 1000 is the records fetched;
- If now I on page 3, meaning (Page number – 1) * 500 = (3 – 1) * 500 = 1000, and Offset is 1000, meaning 1001 to 1500 is the records fetched;

### policylist.php

```
function eins_listPolicy($page, $record ,$search)
{
    //connect to database
    base_connectDatabase();

    $searchs = explode(" ", $search);

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM eins_policy ";
    $countSearch = 0;

    foreach ($searchs as &$value) {
        if ($countSearch == 0) {
            $SQL .= "WHERE ";
        } else {
            $SQL .= "AND ";
        }
        $SQL .=  "(eins_plcy_code LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                    eins_plcy_client IN (SELECT eins_clnt_id FROM eins_client WHERE eins_clnt_full_name LIKE '%".$value."%') OR
                    eins_plcy_insurance_company IN (SELECT eins_icomp_id FROM eins_insurance_company WHERE eins_icomp_name LIKE '%".$value."%') OR
                    eins_plcy_agent IN (SELECT eins_agent_id FROM eins_agent WHERE eins_agent_user_id IN (SELECT base_u_id FROM base_users WHERE base_u_name LIKE '%".$value."%')) OR
                    eins_plcy_policy_type IN (SELECT base_u_id FROM base_users WHERE base_u_name LIKE '%".$value."%') OR
                    eins_plcy_start_date LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                    eins_plcy_end_date LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                    eins_plcy_payment_status = '".$value."' OR
                    eins_plcy_status LIKE '%".$value."%')
               ";
        $countSearch ++;
    }

    $result = base_executeSQL($SQL);
    $total = base_num_rows($result);
    if(is_int($total/$record)) {
        $tpages = $total/$record;
    } else {
        $tpages =  floor($total/$record)+1;
    }

    $start = $record * ($page-1);
    $adjacents = 3;
    $reload = 'policy_list.php';
    $count = 0;
    $zeroRecord = false;

    $RSQL = "LIMIT ".$start.", ".$record."";

    $getPolicySQL = base_executeSQL($SQL.$RSQL);
    while($Policy_row = base_fetch_array($getPolicySQL))
        if (base_num_rows($getPolicySQL)!= 0) {
            $inscompName = eins_getInscompDetail($Policy_row["eins_plcy_insurance_company"]);
            $agentName = eins_getAgentDetail($Policy_row["eins_plcy_agent"]);
            $clientName = eins_getClientDetail($Policy_row["eins_plcy_client"]);
            $polocytypeName = eins_getPolicytypeDetail($Policy_row["eins_plcy_policy_type"]);
            $count = $count + 1;
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>". $count ."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href = \"../einsurance/view_policy.php?id=". $Policy_row["eins_plcy_id"] ."&page=".$page."&record=".$record."&search=".$search."\">". $Policy_row["eins_plcy_code"] ."</a></td>";
                echo "<td>". $polocytypeName['eins_ptype_name'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $inscompName['eins_icomp_name'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $agentName['eins_agent_full_name'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $clientName['eins_clnt_full_name'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $Policy_row["eins_plcy_payment_status"] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $Policy_row["eins_plcy_status"] ."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href = \"../einsurance/edit_policy.php?id=". $Policy_row["eins_plcy_id"] ."&page=".$page."&record=".$record."&search=".$search."\"><img src=\"". BASE_IMG_ICON_EDIT ."\" /></a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href = \"../einsurance/delete_policy.php?id=". $Policy_row["eins_plcy_id"] ."&page=".$page."&record=".$record."&search=".$search."\" onclick=\"return confirm ('".MSG_CONFIRM_DELETE."')\"><img src=\"". BASE_IMG_ICON_DELETE ."\" /></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if (base_num_rows($getPolicySQL)== 0) {
            echo "<tr><td colspan = \"9\" align = \"center\">There is no record!</td></tr>";
            $zeroRecord = true;
        }
        if($zeroRecord == false) {
            echo "<tfoot bgcolor=\"white\">";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan=\"10\">";
                        $record .= "&search=".$search;
                        eins_paginate($reload, $page, $tpages, $adjacents, $record, $total) ;
                    echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
        //close the database
        base_closeDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Do you get all rows returned without the `LIMIT` (i.e. comment out `$SQL`)?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: @tadman Most of these types of questions here do...

Comment: @JBES yes without the LIMIT i get all rows but i need to add LIMIT in it.

Comment: OK, see answer.

Comment: @JBES That's why I flag them like this. You can'd to this. It's completely unacceptable for a public web site and even a "back office" system might be exposed to risks. Firewalls are no guarantee your application will never be accessed externally.

Comment: Flag away, I just agreed with you...

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of `LIMIT` is `LIMIT offset, max rows`

First 500 rows : ... `LIMIT 0,500`

The next 500: ... `LIMIT 500,500` and so on.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Try commenting out your current `$RSQL` line and hard coding something like `$RSQL="LIMIT 0,500";` and if that works you know you have a calculation error somewhere. You can check the entire query with `echo"$SQL$RSQL";` after the `$RSQL` line.

Comment: i have try [$RSQL="LIMIT 0,500"; ]

Comment: As you stated previously that you do get all rows returned without the `LIMIT` ($RSQL) then there is no reason why it shouldn't work. I would check the full query with `echo"$SQL$RSQL";` and see if it actually is what you expect it should be.

Comment: i have try $RSQL="LIMIT 0,500"; but it only show 300 only...not until 500 @JBES

Comment: Then the query itself must only be returning 300 rows. In your original code it seems to use `$record` as the variable for `max_rows` (before 'Refresh' in the image) so that could be passed incorrectly to your function. There are only a few variables that affect this and don't be afraid to check them wherever you need to. `echo"S: $start - R: $record - P: $page - $RSQL";` will show you all of them. `$start` and `$page` should be zero initially and `$record` the number of records to show - if they aren't, trace them back and see why not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @JBES